# Is the hypograph of a bounded function path connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, path-connected

Let $X=\left\{\left(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\right) \in \mathbb{R}^n \vert x_i \geqslant 0, \forall i \mbox{ and }x_1+x_2+...+x_n=1\right\}$. Consider $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
There is a proof in a paper claiming if $f$ is bounded, then the hypograph of $f$ is path connected. It does not elaborate on it so I was wondering how one can prove it.
I tried it but got confused. Path connectedness involves continuity, but $f$ is not necessarily continuous.

Edit: The hypograph of $f$ is $H=\left\{\left(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n, y\right)\in X \times \mathbb{R} \vert y \leqslant f\left(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\right)\right\}$. Consider $\left(x; y\right), \left(x';y'\right)\in H$.
A path is a continuous function $p: \left[0,1\right]\rightarrow H$ such that $p\left(0\right)=\left(x;y\right)$ and $p\left(1\right)=\left(x';y'\right)$.

My attempt: I think I can focus on the case where the projection of the range of $p$ on $X$ is the segment between $x$ and $x'$. I don't know any theorem in the form of "there exists a continuous function such that...". So maybe I should directly construct a path. But I don't know how to solidly describe such a construction, not to mention to ensure its continuity given that $f$ is not necessarily continuous.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for the suggestion. I guess what is missing in my question is the context. But as I said, I find this claim in a paper but the author did not provide an explanation. I don't know how to make it more vivid.

Comment: You gave the context but showed no attempt. Posts where the only "attempt" is "I have no idea" are not well received.

Comment: @AnneBauval "I tried it but got confused. Path connectedness involves continuity, but f
 is not necessarily continuous."---When I wrote the post, I intended to use this sentence to describe my attempt...

Comment: Try *something*: write the definition of the hypograph, take two points in it, try to connect them with a path (using that $f$ is bounded), tell us where you are stuck...

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for the hint. I edited the post to describe my attempt.

Comment: @Ypbor: Your question is perfectly fine; the only additional context that would improve it is to name the specific paper you the statement is from (but that is not really necessary in this case).  It is absolutely not a requirement to include an "attempt" in your question as long as the context is clear.

Comment: +1, your edit was worthy. One more thing you could do to gain some intuition is drawing. For instance when $n=2,$ $X$ is a line segment, so choose some segment $I$ on the $x$-axis of the plane, draw the graph of a bounded function $f:I\to\Bbb R$ and stare at the hypograph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, suppose $X$ is any path-connected space and $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded-below function.  Then the hypograph $H$ of $f$ is connected.  Indeed, let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ be such that $f(x)\geq a$ for all $x\in X$ and suppose $(x,r),(y,s)\in H$.  To get a path from $(x,r)$ to $(y,s)$ in $H$, take a path from $(x,r)$ to $(x,a)$ where only the second coordinate varies (which is possible since $f(x)\geq a$ so $(x,t)\in H$ for all $t$ between $r$ and $a$), then a path from $(x,a)$ to $(y,a)$ where only the first coordinate varies (which is possible since $X$ is path-connected), and finally a path from $(y,a)$ to $(y,s)$ where only the second coordinate varies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I see why I got stuck. I was always trying to construct a path where both coordinates vary but it is not required by the definition of the path.